# getElementsByClassName issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show some team staff in my website, so, I want to show some small info, like picture and name and then, when you click it, it pops up a div with hole info about the person.

I'm trying to do it through getElementsByClassName, but, it's not working, it only works for the first node.

i have two divs, one div named 'popup' which contains info and one full size div with opacity.

so, there's my functions for opening and closing divs:

```
function showWindow(className,number){
var obj = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
$obj[number].fadeIn(1000);
var obj2 = document.getElementById('transparentBox');
obj2.style.display='block';
}

function closeWindow(className,number){
var obj = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
$obj[number].fadeOut("slow");
var obj2 = document.getElementById('transparentBox');
$(obj2).fadeOut(1000);
}
```

The funny thing is that it does work if i click at the first element node, but it doesn't work for the other nodes(i.e. first node = obj[0]). For the other ones, only transparentBox shows up.

the css of both divs:

```
#transparentBox
{
position: fixed;
display:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
z-index: 499;
}
.popup {
position: absolute;
display:none;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width:700px;
padding:20px;
background-color:white;
margin: auto;
z-index:500;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And I'm calling them by More Info

but it's only displaying for the first call showWindow('popup',0), the other calls doesnt display popup, only the transparentBox.

Comment: can you post the relevant part of your html ?

Comment: Where are you declaring `$obj`? I only see `obj`, and you aren't using it anywhere.

Comment: I think he wants to wrap obj with jquery ...

Comment: Putting a `$` in front of a variable doesn't make it a jQuery object.

Comment: Without a complete code (HTML) is non really clear, but if i understand correctly why you don't use $(this) and target the object with this class near $(this)?

Comment: You're still missing the parentheses around `obj`, like @Tahir pointed out: `$(obj[number])`

Comment: Can you copy this: `$(obj[number]).fadeIn(1000);` & paste it in because your edit still misses parenthesis :)

Comment: To clarify what the others are saying. `$` in javascript is not special syntax. It is just a character like `o` and `b` and `j`. So doing `$obj` is the same as doing `Aobj` or `pobj` or `oobj` or `Oobj` or `_obj` (though interestingly not `7obj` because that would be an illegal variable name)

Answer (score 0):

`$(obj[number])` is what you are looking for I think, instead of `$obj(number)`. So your fadeIn/fadeOut should become: `$(obj[number]).fadeIn(1000);`

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it, but it keeps the same thing. I also fixed the code in the post.

Comment: You updated your code in your question with what I am proposing? I don't think I see the `[number]` part in there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what happened wrong.
The problem was that, in my HTML code, the transparentBox div was covering only the first popup div, that's why the other ones didn't show up.

Fixed it. Thanks